# how to draw automatic line between two tap points in a view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4

How can we draw a line automatically after the user taps two different points. The line should be joining those two different points.

What frameworks and methods should be used do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the touched locations in two different `CGPoint` with the help of the `touchedEnded` method ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesEnded%3awithEvent%3a)).

Then, when you have your two points, you can add a new UIView as subview which is aware of the two `CGPoint` and will draw a line in its `drawRect` method. Or do it in the current view, by calling `[view setNeedsDisplay]` to trigger its own `drawRect` method.

---

If you don't know how to draw a simple line with CoreGraphics, here is the beginning :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIBezierPath for this. It can draw line curves if you give points the official documentation is  [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393058/how-do-i-use-uibezierpath-to-draw-a-line-that-follows-a-touch-event) as well