# Drawing a straight line between two points by dragging on IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, drawrect

I have two square images in my UIVIew. Once I drag my finger from one image to another image I want to draw a straight line between them.

I have handled `touchesMoved` method to check when my *touchLocation* reaches the frame of either of the images. So I have handled the logic part of *when* to start drawing and *between which two points.*

I just cant figure out how to do that using `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`. For one thing, I addded an NSlog in my drawRect and I wrote code to draw a line between two lines, even that's not happening.

I checked this [question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050037/how-to-draw-automatic-line-between-two-tap-points-in-a-view-in-iphone), but I want to continue to drag and draw lines between multiple points.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"Draw Rect Entered");
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, 20);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: Is `-drawRect:` definitely being called - are you calling `-setNeedsDisplay` somewhere?

Comment: drawRect is not getting called..no i"m not calling -setneedsDisplay. Where do I have to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the view to update you need to call `-setNeedsDisplay` or `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` on the view that needs to be redrawn. You should do this in the touch handler once you have determined you need to draw the line. This will trigger the `-drawRect:` method on the view- you don't call `-drawRect` directly. For more information, read the [`UIView` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html). I don't know whether you want your line to exist permanently once created- if there's a possibility it might be deleted, I'd add an `if` statement to `-drawRect:` controlled by a boolean determining whether to draw the line or not. Then you can easily switch it off if necessary.

Based on your comments below, I'd create an ivar array in which to store the points for the currently traced line and then loop over them in `-drawRect:`, using the Core graphics functions to draw the line a segment at a time. That way the new segment and all previous segments will be drawn with each redraw.  Since `CGPoint` isn't an obj-c object, you'll either have to create a wrapper class or use obj-C++ and `std::vector`. You could also use a fixed size C-Array, (you mention you have precisely 10 points)- in that case you'd have to preset the unused coordinates to some arbitrary value defined as invalid (e.g. -500,-500) and add logic to not draw line segments if those values are encountered.

Minor point- I wouldn't hardcode the line coordinates - instead you could derive them from the images' `frame` property. That way your code will be more readable and won't break if you change the images or resize them.

Comment: the scenario is : i am dragging between any 10 given points on the view. Once two points are connected a line is drawn between them. Once the drag is continued to another point, then the line is continued between that line. Kinda like the lock screen in android phones.

Comment: The points are UIImages. And i added `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` in viewDidLoad. Still drawRect is not getting called.

Comment: `-viewDidLoad` is called once when the view loads. You need to redraw the view every time you update a line segment. So the call should be in `touchesMoved:` or `touchesEnded:` or wherever you are detecting that a new segment needs to be drawn

Comment: Is everything connected up in IB? I'd stop in the debugger and check that `self.view` isn't `nil`. If it isn't nil, check it's pointing to the right view

Comment: self.view is not nil. And everything in IB is connected. I'm using an OutletCollection, but that shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25850/discussion-between-rich-tolley-and-tushar-koul)

Comment: I created a blank project and added [self.view setNeedsDisplay] in viewDidLoad. Still drawRect is not getting called. also Chat is currently blocked in my current network :@ And I wont be "shifting networks" for another hour.

Comment: No problem.  Is the view in IB set to the custom class that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues I have run into that could cause this problem:
1) Make sure you are calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the main thread
2) If you are working with multiple views make sure you are calling `setNeedsDisplay` against the correct one.
 It is easy to work with one view and forget to call `setNeedsDisplay` against the parent view.